# Type casting errors on a list in python. What is the correct way to make sure this returns as an integer[] not a str list?

Tags: python, list, casting

I'm trying to practice my Python on Leetcode.
I am having a type casting issue trying to return this as an integer list. From a little research, it appears this might be because I am using "range" in my for loop. Can someone please show me the correct way to do this without it causing an error?
Here is my code:

```
class Solution(object):
def removeElement(self, nums, val):
    for i in range(nums.count(val)):
        nums.remove(val)
    return nums
```

Here is the error message:

```
TypeError: [2, 2] is not valid value for the expected return type integer[]
raise TypeError(str(ret) + " is not valid value for the expected return type 
integer[]");
 Line 39 in _driver (Solution.py)
_driver()
```

Line 45 in  (Solution.py)

I get the same error doing it this way too

```
class Solution(object):
def removeElement(self, nums, val):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type val: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    while(nums.count(val) != 0):
        nums.remove(val)
    return nums
```

Comment: First, you shouldn't alter the list while looping over. (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it). Second, `nums` is a list, the return type it's asking for is an integer: `rtype: int`. Removing elements won't turn a list into an integer.

Comment: Given nums was [1, 1, 2, 2, 3] and val =2
my output should be [1, 1, 3]. How do I reference this to be an int??

Comment: I don't know, you didn't tell us what any of this is supposed to do, but `rtype: int` *seems* pretty clear to me. Maybe posting a snippet of the instructions would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

`while` loop:

```
while(nums.count(val) != 0):
        nums.remove(val)
    return len(nums)
```

`for` loop:

```
for i in range(nums.count(val)):
        nums.remove(val)
    return len(nums)
```

Mark had pointed out the return type should be an `int`, so I referenced the `array` as an `int` and it works.
Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue to yours, but solved it with this:

```
while (val in nums):
        nums.remove(val)
    return len(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I changed the language to be python3 instead of python.
And it worked!

Answer (score -1):

if the return type of the function is integer and you try to return None.This error will occur

Uses else block instead to overcome this error

Comment: Is the user's code returning None here, or is it a hypothetical situation? This answer could be improved by showing the situations in which the user's code could return None, and by providing code.